# Incapacidad de bajar el footer

Tags: css, bootstrap

Mi css

```
  html,body{
        height: 100%
    }
    
    .footer {
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }
```

HTML

```
    <footer class="footer bg-dark">
      <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
          <span>Proyecto - Gestion Clinica dental</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Es imposible que el footer baje a abajo , he probado con height:100% en el container pero funciona bien solo cuando la pagina no es mas grande que la pantalla.

Es un proyecto personal pero me gustaría acabarlo

edit: aqui esta el html del container

```
<body>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DentalRenew</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Clientes
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alta Cliente</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Añadir tratamiento</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Citas
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Programar cita</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Empleados
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alta empleado</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Añadir puesto</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>


                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Facturacion
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Añadir Presupuesto</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurar Presupuesto</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estadisticas</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Usuarios
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar nuevo usuario</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4 mt-5">
                            <div class="card-header py-3">
                                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Alta cita</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <form>
                                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Datos cita</h6>
                                  <hr>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Cliente</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Cliente">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputPassword4">Fecha</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="15/02/1995">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Dentista asignado</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputCity">Diagnostico</label>
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                          <option value="volvo">Ortodoncia aguda</option>
                                          <option value="saab">Muelitis</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alta</button>
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="footer bg-dark">
              <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                  <span>Proyecto - Gestion Clinica dental </span>
              </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

analizando con el inspector me queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que version de bootstrap usas? ¿y que clases tiene tu body? Pon el html para que lo podamos ver mejor

Comment: tengo la version 4, añado html del container

Comment: Sigo sin ver la version de bootstrap, ni se si tu body tiene clases o no

Comment: he editado el post con mas info

Comment: Mirate la respuesta de Jheyman Mejia, a mi me funciona con tu código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas CSS adicional, con las clases de Bootstrap bastan.

Como bien te indican en los comentarios, lo primero que debes hacer es darle un alto mínimo a tu `<body>`, lo consigues con `.min-vh-100`, adicional puedes hacerlo flexible y con contenido en columnas, con esto logras que el `<footer>` se pueda posicionar de arriba a abajo.

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
```

Lo último que deberías hacer es añadir la clase `.mt-auto` al elemento `<footer>`, es lo mismo que decir: `margin-top: auto`.

Y el resto lo realiza automático *flexbox.*

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <h1>Hola</h1>

  <footer class="mt-auto footer bg-dark">
    <div class="copyright text-center text-light my-auto">
      <span>Proyecto - Gestion Clinica dental</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Añado edición con tu código, recuerda quitar el CSS innecesario.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>DentalRenew - Gestion de clinicas dentales </title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">


  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div id="content">

    <!-- Topbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DentalRenew</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Clientes
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alta Cliente</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Añadir tratamiento</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Citas
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Programar cita</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Empleados
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alta empleado</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Añadir puesto</a>
            </div>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Facturacion
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Presupuesto</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estadisticas</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                             Usuarios
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listado</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar nuevo usuario</a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Topbar -->
  <div class="container main">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4 mt-5">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Gastos y ingresos</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <canvas id="ingresos"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4 mt-5">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Nº de empleados</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <canvas id="n_empleados"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Main Content -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="mt-auto footer bg-dark">
    <div class="copyright text-center text-light my-auto">
      <span>Proyecto - Gestion Clinica dental</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- End of Footer -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="js/chart.js"></script>

  <script>
    const labels = [
      'Enero',
      'Febrero',
      'Marzo',
      'Abril',
      'Mayo',
      'Junio',
      'Julio',
      'Agosto',
      'Septiembre',
      'Octubre',
      'Noviembre',
      'Diciembre',
    ];

    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Ingresos',
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000],
        },
        {
          label: 'Gastos',
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(51, 116, 255)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(51, 116, 255)',
          data: [0, 2000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000],
        }
      ]
    };

    const configIG = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {}
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(
      $('#ingresos').attr('id'),
      configIG
    );


    const numeroEmpleados = new Chart(
      $('#n_empleados').attr('id'),
      configIG
    );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Esta solución a mi me funciona bien en mis pruebas.

Comment: ami me queda asi como lo pongo aqui https://jsfiddle.net/7Lnbkoda/

Comment: parece que funciona bien pero cuando quitas los estilos que tenia como position absolute  , fijate en el jsfiddle que he puesto , asi es como yo lo veia ( lo acabo de editar)

Comment: En el jsfiddle no has puesto las clases en el body

Comment: si , solo era una demostracion de como me quedaba , con lo Jheyman Mejia ha puesto ya funciona.

Comment: Si, perfecto, ya me lo he imaginado al ver que aceptabas la respuesta

Comment: Usando bootstrap intenta evitar el uso de CSS externo, no vale la pena, bootstrap tiene solución para casi todo con sus clases (y si te pasas al 5 mejor, aunque hay que tener cuidado con algunas cosas, pero cuanto mas tardes mas te arrepentiras despues)

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar `position: absolute;` para que el `bottom: 0;` sea del fondo de tu documento

Si quieres evitar espacios entre el footer y el final del document, añade `margin: 0;` o `margin-bottom: 0;` al body del mismo.

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
    
.footer {      
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el `footer` está después de `.content`, yo creo que añadiendo esto te debería valer

```
.content {
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 60px que es la altura del footer */
}
```

Pero mira a ver que creo que los `div` no los tienes bien cerrados. Después de cerrar el nav cierras un div que creo que no tendrías que hacer. Y por el final tienes un "End Content Wrapper" pero creo que no hay un bloque con esa clase que abra eso

Comment: puede que sea mejor poner position:fixed ? es que el footer se queda clavado en el botton de la pantalla y no baja mas abajo.

Comment: Yo las veces que he necesitado poner el footer justo abajo uso esto, y al footer no le hago nada. Si quieres que quede algo más arriba o abajo puedes ajustar el segundo valor de la resta (a veces los margin pueden hacer que no quede perfecto)

Comment: Acabo de copiar tu HTML para hacer una prueba. Lo que te digo deberías de aplicarlo sobre `.content`, no sobre `.container`. Pero mira a ver que no se si están todos los `div` bien cerrados. Después de cerrar el `nav` cierras un `div` que creo que no tendrías que hacer. Y por el final tienes un "End Content Wrapper" pero creo que no hay clase que abra eso